# Event when clicking on FusionTablesLayer polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I need to know in my javascript each time the client clicks on a polygon. I also need to know what row in my fusion table this corresponds to. Are there events for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there events for doing this?

[FusionTablesMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent)