# Make a polygon link to another page using Google Maps API and Fusion Tables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to figure out how to make a Google Maps polygon (the entire polygon) that is created by Google Fusion tables to be a clickable link to a different page. I had originally thought to add an event listener to the polygon and use "this" but I forgot that that won't work because I'm not generating the polygon, the fusion table is. If anyone could point me in the right direction or help it would be greatly appreciated!

What I have so far is the normal code for a fusion table:

```
var map;
var layer_1;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.205, -97.1325),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    query: {
      select: "col0",

      from: "/*Fustion Table ID*/",

    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I was thinking I could add a listener such as:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (event) {
     //Find the polygon's website URL
    });
```

And use that to trigger a page redirect such as

```
window.location.replace(...)
```

to more or less make the polygon a giant link, but I have been advised against this.

Comment: Sooooo is there a reason for downvoting asking a question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event when clicking on FusionTablesLayer polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815932/event-when-clicking-on-fusiontableslayer-polygon)

Comment: ^ I get that that question mentions Fusion Tables as well, but just linking to one of your answers for another question that lists options for MouseEvents doesn't exactly clear this up.

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [FusionTableLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer) has a [FusionTablesMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent), which contains all the information from that row of the table, in its `row` property:

> row | Object. | A collection of FusionTablesCell objects, indexed by column name, representing the contents of the table row which included the clicked feature.)

Use it like this (the exact code will depend on your table, which you haven't shared):

```
layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    query: {
      select: "col0",

      from: "/*Fustion Table ID*/",

    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });
google.maps.event.addListener(layer_1, 'click', function(evt) {
   // code to open the URL based on the data in that row of your fusion table
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer! Quick question: why is there a "v" as the first argument in the addListener? I would have thought that should be "polygon".

Comment: That was a typo (should have been `layer_1`, the FusionTablesLayer object).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using in case anyone is looking for something similar:

```
var map;
var layer_1;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.205, -97.1325),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    query: {
      select: "col0",

      from: "*** Fusion Table Idea goes here ***",

    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(layer_1, 'click', function(evt) {
   var url = evt.row.website.value;
   console.log(url);
   window.location = url;
  });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```